# Load large XML files

Tags: android, xml, apache-flex, air

I have an xml file (contains images) in the file. The file size is about 50M.
When i read it in flex
on iOS it read well, no problems. Everything is ok 
but on Android always it gives me error #1085.

- The file and code are the same in Android and iOS.
- The XML file is valid - I have tested it on XML validator.

Can anyone tell me what to do?

Comment: What's the full error? Flash is usually pretty good about saying what node is causing the problem.  (e.g. The element type "x" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</x>")

Comment: Yes this is the error The element type "x" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</x> but the XML is correct and 100% and it works fine on IOS

Answer (score 0):

Check the encoding of the file... it might be that the file is saved with a different encoding on android.